# How to get the all the items from the scraped html?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working with this html file:-

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="https://eict.iitr.ac.in/Summeronline.html">
                <div class="date">
                    10
                    <span>
                        Aug
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="detail">
                    <span class="title1">
                        E&amp;ICT Academy (Last date: Aug. 07, 2020)
                    </span>
                    <span class="detailData">
                        Faculty Development Programme on "ICT Tools for Teaching, Learning Process and Institutes"
                    </span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://eict.iitr.ac.in/STCMLDA.html">
                <div class="date">
                    12
                    <span>
                        Aug
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="detail">
                    <span class="title1">
                        E&amp;ICT Academy (Last date: Aug. 09, 2020)
                    </span>
                    <span class="detailData">
                        Online Summer Training Programme on "Data Analytics and Machine Learning using Python"
                    </span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        .......
        .......
    </ul>
</div>
```

For scraping the items of the above file:- i wrote a small script:-

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://www.iitr.ac.in/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"html.parser")
cards = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "wrapper"})

# print(cards.find("span", attrs={"class": "detailData"}).text)
# print(cards.find("div", attrs={"class": "date"}).text)
# print(cards.find("li").a['href'])

for card in cards:
    print("Title:- ", card.find("span", attrs={"class": "detailData"}).text)
    print("Dates:- ",card.find("div", attrs={"class": "date"}).text)
    print("Link:- ",card.find("li").a['href'])
```

and trying to print all `title`, `Dates`, and `Link` out of it but while I am looping over all of the items I am only getting the output of the first part, How can I get all of the items in this manner?

Comment: Try using find_all instead of find.

Comment: doesn't work it pops another error

Comment: Does card.find_all("span", attrs={"class": "detailData"})[0].text print out the first one as well?

Comment: What kind of error

Comment: @arundeepchohan GREAT

Comment: Also are you trying to grab multiple wrapper classes or just one?

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://www.iitr.ac.in/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content,"html.parser")
cardswrapper = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "wrapper"}) #print(cardswrapper.prettify())
cardsa = cardswrapper.find_all("a") #print(cardsa)

for a in cardsa:
    #print(a)
    print("Link:- ",a['href'])
    print("Dates:-", a.div.text)
    print("Title:-", a.find("span", attrs={"class": "detailData"}).text)
    print("\n")
```